# Change a button color on button click temporarily in C#

Tags: c#, button, lambda, serial-port, background-color

This is in **Win forms**

On button click I want to change the color of the button temporarily say only for 1 second and then the button color should get back to the previous color. I used lambda expression and timer for this.

```
    private void btn_Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer t1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            t1.Interval = 1000;
            t1.Tick += (src, ee) => 
            {
                btn_Read.BackColor = Color.Transparent; t1.Stop();
            };
            t1.Start();
            btn_Read.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
            lvwMessages.Items.Clear();
            string strcommand = "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"";
            objShortMessageCollection = ReadSMS(strcommand); // Line wher I am reading messages from the port
            foreach (ShortMessage msg in objShortMessageCollection)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { msg.Sender, msg.Message, msg.Sent, msg.Index });
                item.Tag = msg;
                lvwMessages.Items.Insert(0, item);
            }
            if (lvwMessages.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                status_other.Visible = true;
                status_other.Text = "No messages";
                lbl_total.Text = "Total: 0";
                System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
                timer1.Interval = 2000;
                timer1.Tick += (source, ex) => { status_other.Visible = false; timer1.Stop(); };
                timer1.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                status_other.Visible = false;
                chk_selectmsg.Visible = true;
                btn_delete.Visible = true;
                lbl_total.Text = "Total: " + lvwMessages.Items.Count.ToString(); ;
            }
        }
```

Later in this code I am reading the data from serial port, displaying it, etc. The problem is that the button color doesnot change as I click the button. It takes some time and does not give the desired feel I want. Some times doesn't even change the color. What could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe try this in the mouseDown event? Maybe with the 'btn_Read.BackColor =' statement before creating a timer?

Comment: Are you doing your serial port reading and the other stuff that takes time later in the btn_Read_Click method? If so, it would explain what you're seeing

Comment: @ekholm :Yes but that does not block my UI anyway and fetching the data takes about 500 milliseconds

Comment: @UtkarshSinha : No difference. Same is the result

Comment: @Cdeez: Ok, to be certain about the timing, I would write some timestamp to the console or log file when btn_Read_Click exits, and inside the Tick event handler.

Comment: With no other code in this method, this works fine. It is definitely something further down that you're not showing us. Post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be using **mouse hover** event and **mouse leave** event

Use it this way:

```
    private void btn_Read_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_Read.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    }

    private void btn_Read_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn_Read.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
    }
```

This does'nt require any change in your code and definitely will give you the functionality. See if it helps!

Comment: What if user use keyboard instead of mouse to press button?

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid having work-intensive code on the UI thread

to get the desired effect, sepperate the code for the UI from the code that does the work ...

when the button is clicked, change its appearence and start some background task (threadpool,backgroundworker,etc) that does the work

be aware that you can interact with a control only from the thread it was created on, so to display your data or interact with the UI, you will have to invoke the UI thread (see [Control.Invoke(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx))

if you have a lot of UI reseting stuff like that, you should think about a timer on the form, to check every let's say 200ms if there is something to be reset/done

you could use a sorted list with tuples (Datetime,delegate) that are executed and removed once the time has come ...

Answer (score 0):

Write the rest of code in thread and fire that thread. this will make your UI responsive and will give you the desired output you want for button. Or use btnedit.[Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) just after changing color to force button to redraw itself