# Change control colour, and change it back to original

Tags: c#, winforms, button, background, click

I want to change colour of the button momentarily to show that button has been pressed. How can I achieve this in C#? I can change the background color easily enough like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Green;    
}
```

of the button, but how do I revert those changes after a delay?

Comment: or asp.net webforms?

Comment: i am making a winform application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change a button color on button click temporarily in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807365/change-a-button-color-on-button-click-temporarily-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, but that question doesn't seem to have an accepted / acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Azure;
    var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private  void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor =  SystemColors.Control;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Color btnBackColor;
Timer timer = new Timer();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnBackColor = button1.backColor;
    button1.BackColor = Color.Green;    
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = btnBackColor;
    timer.Enabled=false;
}
```

And add the following lines to the constructor:

```
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Elapsed = 2000;
```